# Show that $\int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} f(x, y) dx dy = 0.$

Tags: integration, proof-verification

> Let
>
> $$f(x, y) :=
> \begin{cases}
> sgn(xy) \over x^2 + y^2,  & \text{$(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \setminus ${0}$$} \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> be a function with
>
> $${\rm sgn}(xy) := 
> \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{$xy > 0$} \\
> -1, & \text{$xy < 0$} \\
> 0, & \text{$xy = 0$} 
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that
>
> $$\int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} f(x, y) dx dy = 0.$$

**My attempt:**

First, we assume that $y > 0$. This means that $sgn(xy) = 1$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$ and $sgn(xy) = -1$ for $x \in (-\infty, 0)$. We are then allowed to write the inner integral like this:

$$\int_0^\infty {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx + \int_{-\infty}^0  {-1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx = \int_0^\infty {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx - \int_{-\infty}^0  {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx.$$

Both integrals are identical, and it can be shown that they are finite. Hence, the value of the inner integral is $0$ and so is the value of the double integral.

Now we need to assume that $y < 0$. This means that $sgn(xy) = -1$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$ and $sgn(xy) = 1$ for $x \in (-\infty, 0)$. Now we get:

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx + \int_0^\infty  {-1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx - \int_0^\infty  {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx.$$

Once again, both integrals are identical and finite, hence, the inner integral equals $0$, and so does the double integral.

Comment: Seems the attempt written is sound. So what's the issue here?

Comment: I'm just wondering whether it's correct or not. :)

Comment: I think this is correct. Put this up as an answer. "Self-learner" :)

Comment: I will wait a little bit, maybe someone else finds a mistake. :) But thank you very much so far!

Comment: My solution is wrong. $f = f_+ - f_-$, not $f = f_+ + f_-$

Comment: ... but one doesn't need it, I can simply split up the sgn-function in the intervals.

Comment: I added the tag [[proof-verification]]

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct, well done! This is a pretty general argument, as you might notice that if we replace $sgn(xy)/(x^2+y^2)$ with any odd function of $x$ (or of $y$) the argument works just as well.